# Symfony 3.2 Easyadminbundle how to hide/remove default actions link

Tags: symfony, symfony2-easyadmin

I was wondering if someone can tell me how to hide the action links from the list view base on a status column.

More details: I have a list view in which shows a list of items, In this list I have column named status. For each record in this list in which status is set to close, I would like to hide the edit/delete and other custom actions links from the list. Is this doable? if so, how?

Thanks

Comment: May be by hooking an event, but not sure it can be done. https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/book/7-complex-dynamic-backends.md

Comment: @Coil I reviewed all of their documentation, but I still haven't figure out how to change the actions links based on status. Basically, if I have an item with status A I don't want to show the edit button. Docs shows how to remove from entity but not from code

Comment: I think you could override the @EasyAdmin/default/includes/_actions.html.twig template. To try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to override just the `item_actions` Twig block in the `list.html.twig` template used by that entity. In practice, if the entity is called `Order`, a template like this should work:

```
{# app/Resources/views/easy_admin/Order/list.html.twig #}
{% extends '@EasyAdmin/default/list.html.twig' %}
{% block item_actions %}
    {% if item.status != 'close' %}
        {{ parent() }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock item_actions %}
```

Comment: Thank you. I took this route as a solution